# how to take the number of an int input from the user and at the same time store the user's input?

Tags: java

this program is a magic date program (day times month="year as a two digits number") like 06\10\60 ... I want to make a condition ... if the day or the month or the year entered are more or less than 2 digits should display an error message ... I tried this

```
 System.out.println("Please enter the day as a two digit Number");
 day=key.nextInt();
 day1=day.length();
```

but it did not work ... so I tried this :

```
System.out.println("Please enter the month as a two digit Number");
month1=key.next().length();
month=key.nextInt();
```

but when i run the program ... it requires two inputs not one 
So help me out

Comment: You are reading an int and you are trying to use `.length()`?

Comment: Why don't you convert the int temporaliy to a string for checking the length?

Comment: @gtgaxiola I also need the number of the int entered ...

Comment: @reporter I think the answer is because it's less clear and inefficient.

Comment: What is the datatype of `key`? That way we can know what the datatype of `key.nextInt()` is.

Comment: Why is anyone helping anyone who concludes their question with "So help me out"

Comment: @NoGodbutALLAH There is a concept called "politeness". The purpose of this site to allow people to ask for help, not demand it. I would conclude this question with something like "Any help would be appreciated" or "Thank you for your help", or just let your question stand on its own. But the use of the imperative "So help me out" is rude. We're here to help, not be bossed around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `nextInt()` but you would like two-digit numbers like `06` which is not a valid integer.

It will be better to:

1. Scan the input as a String. `String day = scan.nextLine();`
2. Validate for correct input by using `day.matches("\\d{2}")`
   (This will only match any pairing of [0-9] and don't have to worry about other characters)
3. If it Validates then you can get your Integer:  `Integer realDay = Integer.valueOf(day);`
4. Perform further Validation to test the range (1-31 for Days) (1-12 for Months) (1-28 or 1-29 for February depending on the Year)  etc.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
day = key.nextInt();
int dayAbs = Math.abs(day);      // to handle negatives
if(dayAbs >= 10 && dayAbs <= 99) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `day > 99 || day < 10`? The OP says **...are more or less than 2 digits...**, so anything with 2 digits should be good. (leaving aside that a day of the month of 50 is non-sensical, so number of digits is poor validation... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by converting int to string and then by checking the length of the string.

```
String s = Integer.toString(day);
if(s.length() <= 2 && !(s.length() < 1)){
    System.out.println("Good");
}else
    System.out.println("Bad");
```

Answer (score 0):

to test for the number of digits in an int primitive try this

```
int number = ...;
// or however you get the number

int length = (int)(Math.log10(number)+1);

if(length!=2) {
    // no!
} else {
    // yuss!
}
```

Comment: or this `int length = Integer.valueOf(number).toString().length();`

Answer (score 0):

Except using int use string then check the length of the input. This code is only a base. It is stored in result. Then after the check use Integer.parseInt(result);

```
System.out.println("Please enter two digits:");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String result = scan.next();
     if(result.length()>2 || result.length()<2)
         System.out.println("ERROR");
     else
         System.out.println("Success");
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it seems that you want to enforce the length of the string so that the user has to type `06` instead of `6`.

If so:

```
String dayString = key.next();
if(dayString.length() != 2) {
    // throw error
}
int day = Integer.parseInt(dayString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int day=key.nextInt();
String dayString = "";
if(day> 30 || day <0){ System.out.println("Error1");}
else if(day<10 ){ dayString = "0" + String.valueOf(day);}
else{dayString = String.valueOf(day);}
```

here u have ur day in 2 digits as a string,more easy to manipulate.
u can also try Date class (java.util.Date)

Answer (score 0):

i don't understand that why you are using key but i think that Buffer reader can solve your problem here is the example!

```
int month=0,length=0;
        String len=null;
        BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Please enter the month as a two digit Number");
        len=bf.readLine();
        length=len.length();
        month=Integer.parseInt(len);
        if(length==2)
        {
            System.out.println("Here you go month is two digit!");
        }
        else
        {
           //inform user that month is not 2 digits!
        }
```